# I am getting 500 Internal Error IIS 7. Where can I find Error logs for my Server while installing Drupal

Tags: drupal, iis, iis-7, error-log

I have a Drupal Site that I am copying from one server to another.I checked all the connections, permissions But I am getting Internal 500 Server Error. Can anyone suggest me the place where I can see the error log for IIS 7.0? 
my drupal version is 6.0